# Database-Centric Vs Tired Architecture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Consider 3 applications:

1. One is for a fitness club that has a backend database and offers some services on the website,
2. another is an e-commerce site, with heavy dependence on Database,
3. a point of sale application with heavy use of database

I need to choose among tiered architecture and database-centric, as defined in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440366).
I can't seem to find resources that discuss exact motivations of choosing one over the other, apart from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-centric_architecture), which states:

> using stored procedures that run on database servers, as opposed to
> greater reliance on logic running in middle-tier application servers
> in a multi-tier architecture. The extent to which business logic
> should be placed at the back-end versus another tier is a subject of
> ongoing debate. For example, Toon Koppelaars presents a detailed
> analysis of alternative Oracle-based architectures that vary in the
> placement of business logic, concluding that a database-centric
> approach has practical advantages from the standpoint of ease of
> development and maintainability.

It seems to me point of sale should follow database-centric, and fitness center application should follow tiered architecture, but I am not sure about the ecommerce. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

[image: Tiered architecture]

**and Database Centric Architecture:**

[image: Database Centric Architecture]

Answer (score 0):

We can create an application with either of the architecture styles. The selection of the architecture must be done based on the requirements of the system.
Here are a few of them :

- Consistency
- Availability
- Amount of data the application would be dealing with
- Type of data (Structured (tables & rows) / Un-Structured (documents,Media files,sensor data)
- Amount of traffic the application should withstand
- Latency per request

and there are many more to look for as per our application needs.

As I understand from database-centric style should only be used for applications that heavily rely on the features of the database such as stored procedures, triggers. And any modern-day application such as e-commerce websites etc must not be database-centric. These applications are ever-evolving and need to be highly scalable in nature to appropriately adjust to future demands.

Having said that, it is not written on the stone that we need to use a specific architecture for specific kinds of applications. We need to carefully evaluate the requirements/expectations of users from our applications. Which would provide us with the rightful insights to pick the appropriate architectural style.

Would like to recommend the following for further reading.

- [Designing Data-Intensive Applications: The Big Ideas Behind Reliable, Scalable, and Maintainable Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321)
- [web-application-architecture-101](https://www.educative.io/module/lesson/web-application-architecture-101)